# Problematic rendering of mark=+ in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\xdef\doPlotCoords{}
\foreach \r in {0,1,...,10}{%
  \xdef\tempCoords{} %
  \foreach \c in {0,1,...,10}{ %
    \xdef\tempCoords{\tempCoords (\r,\c)\space}
  } % end \foreach \c
  \let\addplot\relax
  \xdef\doPlotCoords{ \doPlotCoords
  \addplot+[color=blue,mark=+,mark options={blue},] coordinates{ \tempCoords };}
} % end \foreach \r
\typeout{\meaning\doPlotCoords}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[only marks]
\doPlotCoords
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output for me is like this (click for full size):

[image: test71.png]

Note that the `+` marker symbols in the first columns (0-4) are symmetric, then in columns 5-9 they are asymmetric, and then in column 10 they are symmetric again? And this is apparently not an anti-aliasing problem (the full-size image is 300 dpi rendering of the pdf)

Even worse, if I comment out the `\begin{axis} %[only marks]`:

[image: test72.png]

... then somehow columns 5-9 are dashed, and the rest arent??

What is going on here - and how could I get the plot to show all `+` markers the same everywhere (symmetrical as in the first column), and all lines between them the same as well?

Comment: This happens because you're using `\addplot+[options]`. The `+` specifies that you want to provide options in addition to keeping the normal cycle list active, which uses dashed lines for some of the plots. Remove the `+` and everything will look as expected.

Answer (score 2):

CW from the comments:

Using `\addplot+` means that style options are *appended* to the default style (a `cycle list`). So the `color` specified by the default cycle list is overwritten by `blue` but other options (namely line style/dashing) are not.

Correct the problem by simply using `\addplot` instead (unless you really do want to append only selected options, in which case you'll need to add all those things you do not want to change):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\xdef\doPlotCoords{}
\foreach \r in {0,1,...,10}{%
  \xdef\tempCoords{} %
  \foreach \c in {0,1,...,10}{ %
    \xdef\tempCoords{\tempCoords (\r,\c)\space}
  } % end \foreach \c
  \let\addplot\relax
  \xdef\doPlotCoords{ \doPlotCoords
  \addplot[color=blue,mark=+,mark options={blue},] coordinates{ \tempCoords };}
} % end \foreach \r
\typeout{\meaning\doPlotCoords}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[only marks]
\doPlotCoords
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]